# Is there a Top Ten Noob Mistakes list for iPhone?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, new-users

I've been answering a lot of questions by novice devs or people new to iOS.  Of course they all make the same mistakes (that I did) so I wonder:

is there an established place to post a list of things for novices to do,

such as:

- Clean all targets, Reset Contents
         and Settings in the simulator
- Enable NSZombieEnabled
- Learn to use NSLog
- Pushing a view onto a null nav
  controller does not work
- Send message to nil object no-ops
- Hook up your IBOutlets to your properties
- Release any memory you own

  etc.

**Update**:
 Here's a link to a [blog entry](http://blog.cagefreesoftware.com/?page_id=4) - is this appropriate for the iphone tag wiki?
Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea for a blog post.

Comment: ... or the tag wiki.

Comment: Had to read this three times before I figured out it was on topic

Answer (score 5):

You could edit the tag wiki and add the necessary information as short pieces of information or as links to external resources.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iphone/info

Answer (score 2):

If there are other answers on Stack Overflow covering these issues, point them to these answers. I believe most of them have been covered already.

The problem then becomes how to catalogue these answers. I believe a tag wiki would be the best place to gather them, and you could refer users to the tag wiki.

And now the problem becomes: which tag? It seems that users on Stack Overflow prefer the [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) tag, although many other tags are related and more suitable for some of those questions: [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), [cocoa-touch](/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch), [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) (and variations), [iphone-sdk-4.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4.0) and variations.

I think there have been efforts on meta to organise tags related to iOS and Mac OS X development. I’m not sure if there’s been consensus, though.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fill the tag wiki with what could be a lot of detail, how about creating [iphone-faq](/questions/tagged/iphone-faq) in the same vein as [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b-faq/info). Then, all you need to do is tag all the already written questions with this tag and fill in the blanks. [Relevant discussion (for C++) here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag).

Comment: Better yet, [ios-faq].  I cringe when people call it iPhone OS...

Answer (score -4):

If you already have written answers for it, then write a question for it as well:

Q: What are common mistakes for iPhone?

A: this, this and this(links)

Answer it yourself, and then anytime someone has a question which can be fully answered by your answer, vote to close as a duplicate.

I'd get feedback on this answer before actually doing it though. I'm not sure how people feel about closing a question as duplicate, just because another answer works for them(though, the question itself is not a duplicate)

Comment: -1, list of x question.